# asp.net c# autocomplete with textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i am trying to use the autocomplete with textbox using jquery. I am not getting any error. But the code is doing nothing.

please find my code.
 this is my form code. 
html:

```html
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <link href="/dist/css/jquery.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/dist/js/jquery.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".txtVendor").autocomplete("/DataAccess/get-vendor-list.aspx", {
                width: 230, selectFirst: false, scrollHeight: 90, mustMach: true
            });

            $(".txtVendor").result(function (event, data, formatted) {
                if (data) {
                    $(".hidVendor").val(data[1].trim());
                }
            });
        });
    </script> 
   
</asp:Content>
```

```html
 <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblVendor" runat="server" Text="Vendor Name"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtVendor" runat="server" Text="" class="form-control" CssClass="txt Vendor" Style="width: 100%;"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="hidVendor" runat="server" CssClass="hidVendor"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
```

And the get-vendor-list.aspx is below.

```html
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string retStr = "";
        if (Request.QueryString["q"] != null)
        {
            VendorList lst = new VendorList();
            VendorDB db = new VendorDB();
            db.strFilter = " AND VendorID like '%" + Request.QueryString["q"].ToString() + "%' OR VendorName like '%" + Request.QueryString["q"].ToString() + "%'";
            lst = db.GetListForGrid(10, 1, "VendorName");
            if (lst != null)
            {
                if (lst.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Vendor itm in lst)
                    {
                        retStr += itm.VendorName + " | " + itm.VendorID + Environment.NewLine;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Response.Write(retStr);
    }
```

Masterpage already mention the js files.

```html
<script src="/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/jQueryUI/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css"rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
        
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

No errors and no result. thanks for the support.

Comment: Does the Page_Load method get called at all?You can test that by setting a breakpoint on the first curly bracket. Furthermore you can monitor network traffic with F12 > Network tab.

Comment: no its not, i tried to put breakpoint. but not hit the breakpoint.